# Temp table behavior in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am executing below script.

```
declare @id int = 0

while(@id < 10)
begin
    declare @tbl as table (id int)

    insert into @tbl values(@id)
    set @id = @id + 1

    SELECT * FROM @tbl
end
```

I am getting result like below.

[image: Result]

but this script should give only one row every time in temp table because temp table is declaring every time in while loop and I am inserting only one value in table.

I don't understand this behavior of temp table, please suggest.

Comment: Your script will give all the rows inserted into the table since you are using select * from table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table variables inside while loop not initializing everytime : SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751096/table-variables-inside-while-loop-not-initializing-everytime-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Transact-SQL Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.

Each `DECLARE` is only "read" once:

- SQL Server parce the code and read all the `DECLARE` statements at compile time.
- It then reserves memory for theses variables.
- Code can then use them from the location of their respecting `DECLARE` until the end of the script.

If we look at your script, @tbl has already been reserved in memory when line 1 is executed but the variable can only be used once the script reach line 5. However it is not reserved again and again on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: ok, but when system execute the while block second time, how system knows that there is already a temp table with named @tbl and it already contains value 0 there

Comment: Because you are using a table variable and variables in general are reserved at compile time before the execution start.

Comment: then in second iteration it should not generate exception like The variable name '@tbl' has already been declared ?

Comment: No because declare is only parsed and used at compile time in order to reserve the variable. Then during execution and iteration of the loop, this is not read anymore. It already knows that it has been declared and the variable is valid.

Comment: Thank you i understand that  :)